# How to separate Corporate and Normal user in woocommerce?

Tags: wordpress

I'm not an experienced developer but trying to understand and need help how to make my Woocommerce store with two separate users.

I want to have products for normal users and corporate where I want to keep separate prices on products. And two separate registration and login pages for normal users and corporate account.

Corporate accounts and prices will differ from customer prices and accounts. 
Website default will be shown prices for customer and there will be a link for corporate.

thank you

Answer (score 0):

Yes, this can be done.
Two types of customers can be done with user roles.
You will need some dev knowledge to place the correct login and registration forms on different pages. The login is less complicated since once the user is registered to a role, no need for different login form. Registration needs some work to make the user role according to the form used.

Different prices also can be achieved using ready-made plugins.

[User Role](https://wordpress.org/plugins/user-role-editor/) Editor plugin will help you create a new role for the corporates.

[Dynamic Discounts](https://codecanyon.net/item/woocommerce-dynamic-pricing-discounts/7119279?ref=NeutrinoTeam) plugin will help you create different discount rate for the new user roles.